# Invalid command 'Auth_MYSQLhost'

Tags: apache, .htaccess

> Invalid command 'Auth_MYSQLhost', perhaps misspelled or defined by a
>   module not included in the server configuration

I'm following [this](http://www.widexl.com/tutorials/htaccess.html) guide for configuring .htaccess for MySQL login. I'm running Apache but I get the error above. This is the code:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "MySQL Member Page"

Auth_MYSQLhost localhost
Auth_MYSQLusername root
Auth_MYSQLpassword root
Auth_MYSQLdatabase login
Auth_MYSQLpwd_table administrators
Auth_MYSQLuid_field username
Auth_MYSQLpwd_field password
Auth_MYSQL_EncryptedPasswords off
require valid-user
```

It doesn't even try to connect to mysql but fail as soon as it reads `Auth_MYSQLhost`. Why is this? I've already tried with `AuthMYSQLhost`, `authMYSQLhost`, `auth_MYSQLhost` with no luck.

Comment: Did you load the mod_auth_mysql module into your Apache HTTPd server ?

Comment: Nope, I thought it was already included in the distribution...

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to install auth_mysql Apache module.
If you are running Debian/Ubuntu, on terminal, do this:

```
 sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql
```

Then activate the module:

```
 sudo a2enmod auth_mysql
```

And restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And now it will works.